# svnadmin dump : use deltas in dump output

Tags: svn

What does it mean to "use deltas in dump output" with `svnadmin dump`?

Does this mean to only print the differences between the commits for each svn dump log?

From what I tried, it appears that this is true ; however, I wanted to confirm this as this has a fairly big impact on what I'm doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, more information is [in the manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnadmin.html#svn.ref.svnadmin.sw.deltas):

> The second useful option is --deltas. This option causes svnadmin dump
>   to, instead of emitting full-text representations of file contents and
>   property lists, emit only deltas of those items against their previous
>   versions. This reduces (in some cases, drastically) the size of the
>   dump file that svnadmin dump creates. There are, however,
>   disadvantages to using this option—deltified dump files are more
>   CPU-intensive to create, cannot be operated on by svndumpfilter, and
>   tend not to compress as well as their nondeltified counterparts when
>   using third-party tools such as gzip and bzip2.